# Win8 Metro IE10 Drag-N-Drop / Slider Issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-8, microsoft-metro, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-10

I was trying some **slider / drag-n-drop** demos of JQuery Mobile, Kendo UI and other javascript frameworks, but none seem to work in the Metro version of IE10 on my tablet (running Windows 8 Consumer Preview).

I remember there was a similar issue on IOS, but using most frameworks it's now working on my iPad.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Is there any JS framework that has addressed this issue?
Could this be something that is still to be fixed by Microsoft before final release of Win8?

Cheers,
Ray

Comment: I just found the IE test Drive site: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/TouchFirstControls/Default.html , http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_2d-transforms.htm , http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/BrickBreaker/Default.html they showed that sliders and drag-n-n drop can work in IE, unfortunately they did not work great on the iPad... If you know a framework that targets both, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that IE10 introduces [MSPointerEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441233.aspx), which are probably not well supported by most frameworks, at least yet.

**Update:** Kendo UI supports MSPointerEvents since Q3 2012. As of Q1 2013 all framework widgets also work properly in IE10 when content is pinch-zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 10 has a more abstact event model when it comes to touch, mouse, or pen events. Rather than having events like *touchstart* or *mousedown*, Internet Explorer 10 has an arguably superior model consisting of a much simpler *MSPointerDown* which is fired for all types of inputs, including fingers, mice, or pens.

Unfortunately, as you've noticed, there isn't a great deal of support in popular libraries and frameworks, though I suspect there are a few good reasons why this is the case:

1. IE10 is still technically incomplete.
2. IE10 is currently not available on Windows 7 (though it will be released on Windows 7 eventually)
3. IE10 currently requires the installation of unfinalized versions of Windows 8

These reasons, among more I'm sure, have likely caused the developers behind major frameworks and libraries to hold off on any serious investment of their time to target the new browser from Microsoft. That being said, I do know *personally* of some very key players from the jQuery project who have been keeping a close eye on Microsoft's new pointer model. I suspect the same can be said for other teams.